# How do I fix this expression to hide / show report elements?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I'm using SSRS 2008 R2 to generate a report with subreports. I'm trying to conditionally hide a subreport (embedded inside a rectangle and then hiding the rectangle) using the expression below.

I modeled the expression after various samples I found online but nothing works. The `Fields!CountABC.Value` portion of the expression is underlined in a red, squiggly line with a tooltip that states "Unknown collection member". I know the member exists. I selected it from a list and verified it exists in the dataset.

```
=IIF(Sum(Fields!CountABC.Value, "DataSet1")>= 1, True, False)
```

How do I fix this expression?

Comment: Your expression looks okay to me, are you sure it doesn't work? What happens if you just put `Sum(Fields!CountABC.Value, "DataSet1")` in a TextBox?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The correct values appear in a textbox. The correct integer values appear and, in another textbox, the correct boolean is displayed. So why doesn't the rectangle hide / show based on the bool?

Comment: Not sure what's going on but I restarted VS and recreated the expression. It seems to be working fine now.